# RAII in pybind11 does not call destructor when added calllbacks

Tags: python, pybind11, raii, gil

Here is the pybind11 code, which defined a Stream class and exported it to python3.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <pybind11/detail/common.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>
#include <pybind11/gil.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <thread>

namespace py = pybind11;

class Stream {
public:
  std::thread *thr;
  Stream() {}
  void addCallback(std::function<void()> func) { thr = new std::thread(func); }
  ~Stream() {
    if (thr != nullptr && thr->joinable()) {
        thr->join();
        delete thr;
    }
    std::cout << "stream dtor" << std::endl;
  }
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
  py::class_<Stream>(m, "Stream")
      .def(py::init<>())
      .def("add_callback", &Stream::addCallback);
}
```

The python3 code to test it:

```
def func():
    print("xxx ")
a = Stream()
a.add_callback(func)
```

When execute this python script using python3 test.py, the program exits with no print.
There are 3 scenarios that destructor worked:

1. do not add callback

```
def func():
    print("xxx ")
a = Stream()
#a.add_callback(func)
```

2. create the stream in a function, and call the function

```
def func():
    print("xxx ")
def call_func():
    a = Stream()
    a.add_callback(func)
call_func()
```

3. create the Stream as normal but before exit, call time.sleep(1)

```
def func():
    print("xxx ")
a = Stream()
a.add_callback(func)
time.sleep(1) # or some other value
```

I have done some research for it. Here is my findings:

- The first scenario does not make Stream related with other threads, so it will be collected when python run gc.
- The second scenario does trouble me, I gauss it's because the gc can make sure that Stream instance will not be used again, so it's also collected.
- The third scenario kept python's gil from exiting, so that the callback will be executed by gil.

Sometimes, the callback will execute part of it, see the following code:

```
def func():
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print(i/10)
a = Stream()
a.add_callback(func)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

it will print:

```
0.0 
0.1 
0.2 
0.3
```

Which means the callback it executed until the main thread finish the last line.
Here are my questions:

1. When python is about to exit, assume it will run gc, destruct all objects including Stream, why doesn't it call Stream's destructor? It seemed the destructor is omitted and gil is gone before the callback finished.
2. What happened after the last line finished?

Comment: In scenario "do not add callback", the destructor dereferences `thr` that was never initialized. Kinda surprised it didn't outright crash.

Comment: @DanMašek when dtor get called, it will see if the thread is joinable:

Comment: I know what that code means, and I'm not really sure where you see me asking for explanation. | Let me try again: What is `thr` pointing to, when you have only called the constructor, using the C++ code your provided in the beginning of the question?

Comment: Anyway, this seems like a scenario where a context manager would be appropriate.

Comment: @DanMašek Yes you are right. The pointer is not initialized, I will correct the code. By the way, I tested another cpp code, which does not raise exceptions:
```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::thread* thr;
    std::cout << thr->joinable() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```
It will print "1" in the console.

Comment: You can't assume gc will run or objects will be destructed. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__